# pythonでPDF作成について

Tags: python

PyQtを用いてHTMLファイルからPDFを作成しているのですが
エラーが出て動きません
PDFは作成できるのですが中は真っ白なPDFだけで困っています

エラーコードは
__agent_connection_block_invoke_2:Connection error - Connection invalid

こんな感じで出てきてどうすればいいのかわからないので教えてくださいお願いします

Python2.7.10でPyQt4を使っています
コードはこちらになります

```
#coding utf-8
import markdown
import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPrinter
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
printer = QPrinter()

def load_finished():
    global web
    global printer

    web.print_(printer)
    QApplication.exit()

def md2html(_fileName):
    md=markdown.Markdown()
    text=""
    for i in open(_fileName,"r"):
         text+=i
    text=md.convert(text)

    fn=open("test.html","w")
    fn.write(text)
    fn.close()

def html2pdf():
    global app
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Landscape)
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
    printer.setResolution(QPrinter.HighResolution)
    printer.setOutputFileName('test.pdf')

    web.loadFinished.connect(load_finished)
    web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.html')))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())




md2html("aaa.md")
html2pdf()
```

Comment: PythonとPyQtのバージョンや、エラーが出ているコードなどを質問の編集で追加して下さい。

Comment: コードを全角スペースでインデントしないで下さい。コードはそのままの形で貼り付けて下さい。貼り付けた後でコードを選択し、編集欄の上にあるかっこ「 { } 」 のアイコンを押せば、Markdownの「コードサンプル」用のインデントが足され、綺麗に表示されます。

Comment: すみません修正しましたよろしくお願いします

Answer (score 2):

以下のコードの、

```
web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.html')))
```

`QUrl.fromLocalFile` に指定するファイルパスは絶対パスである必要があります。これは、内部で `file://...` の形式に変換されるためです。実際、`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'test.html')` は `test.html` になってしまいます(相対パス)。

したがって、ここは以下の様にします。

```
web.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath('test.html')))
```

また、`md.convert()` は HTML ヘッダを付加しませんので、このままでは UTF-8 文字列が正しく扱われない事になります(いわゆる「文字化け」が発生します)。そのため、`Content-Type` を追加します。

```
text=md.convert(text)
fn=open("test.html","w")
=>
text = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"></head><body>' + md.convert(text) + '</body></html>'
fn=open("test.html","w")
```

※ もっと良い方法があるかもしれません。

Comment: うまくいきました！ありがとうございます！！
ですがまだエラーが出てきてしまうのですがこれはどういう意味なのでしょうか？

`2015-11-19 23:45:34.047 python[7176:494824] __agent_connection_block_invoke_2: │
Connection error - Connection invalid`

Comment: おそらく、OSX のプリントシステム関連のエラーだと思います。つまり、`web.print_(printer)` の実行で、プリンタにも出力しようとしているのではないかと…回避策があるかどうか調べてみます。